# React useState, multiple initial conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Have a question regarding useState, is it a good idea to use multiple conditions when setting the initial useState value?

Just got a hold of a project and I'm seeing a lot of this, to me it seems like it will cause performance issues/unnecessary renders?

Example:

```
function MyComponent({ isInitialized, isValueTrue }) {
    const isMammal = useMammal();

    const [showBanner, setBanner] = useState(!isMammal && isInitialized && isValueTrue);

    useEffect(() => {
        // dome something
    }, [showBanner]);
}
```

Comment: The initial value for `useState` only really matters at first render, but the join expression ( `!isMammal && isInitialized && isValueTrue`)  will still be computed during next loops of render, while not trigger re-render.  And it looks like the computing is really trival so may not cause performance issue either.

In conculstion, it may only cause readability problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given Code:

> ```
> function MyComponent({ isInitialized, isValueTrue }) {
>   const isMammal = useMammal();
>
>   const [showBanner, setBanner] = useState(
>     !isMammal && isInitialized && isValueTrue
>   );
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     // dome something
>   }, [showBanner]);
>
>   ...
> }
> ```

### Question 1

> is it a good idea to use multiple conditions when setting the initial
> useState value?

It's not a bad idea if that is what you are concerned with. The initial value passed to the `useState` hook is only evaluated once when the component mounts.

See [Lazy Initial State](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)

> The `initialState` argument is the state used during the initial
> render. In subsequent renders, it is disregarded. If the initial state
> is the result of an expensive computation, you may provide a function
> instead, which will be executed only on the initial render:
>
> ```
> const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
>   const initialState = someExpensiveComputation(props);
>   return initialState;
> });
> ```

## Question 2

> Just got a hold of a project and I'm seeing a lot of this, to me it
> seems like it will cause performance issues/unnecessary renders?

Nope, it doesn't appear this is possible with this code. React components rerender for 1 of 3 reasons:

1. The component enqueues a state update and triggers a rerender.
2. A passed props value changes value.
3. The parent or an ancestor component rerenders, and subsequently rerenders its entire sub-ReactTree.

I would suggest not using state at all here. It's actually considered a React anti-pattern to store derived state in state. In this case the `showBanner` value is easily derived from the `useMammal` hook's return value and the passed props. You should just compute the `showBanner` value locally in the component.

Example:

```
function MyComponent({ isInitialized, isValueTrue }) {
  const isMammal = useMammal();

  const showBanner = !isMammal && isInitialized && isValueTrue;

  useEffect(() => {
    // do something
  }, [showBanner]);

  ...
}
```

If for some reason the is recomputed too often per one of the reasons listed above and/or the expression is "heavy" then you can/should memoize it via the `useMemo` hook.

Example:

```
function MyComponent({ isInitialized, isValueTrue }) {
  const isMammal = useMammal();

  const showBanner = useMemo(() => {
    return !isMammal && isInitialized && isValueTrue;
  }, [isMammal, isInitialized, isValueTrue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // do something
  }, [showBanner]);

  ...
}
```